# Add bash autocompletion to a python script

Tags: python, bash, autocomplete

I'm using `readline` in my script to offer input history recording and history-based autocompletion.

now i want it to complete bash command as well. eg. suggest executables in `$PATH`, list items in given directory.

do i have to achieve this manually?

```py
histfile = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser("~"), ".python_history")
with open(histfile) as f:
    for line in f:
        for item in line.strip().split():
            commands.append(item)

def completer(text, state):
options = [i for i in commands if i.startswith(text)]
if state < len(options):
    return options[state]
else:
    return None


readline.parse_and_bind("tab: complete")
readline.set_completer(completer)

try:
    readline.read_history_file(histfile)
    # default history len is -1 (infinite), which may grow unruly
    readline.set_history_length(1000)
except FileNotFoundError:
    pass

atexit.register(readline.write_history_file, histfile)
```

Comment: what have you done thus far? can we see your code?

Comment: ok im posting my code